# Replacement for Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthorizationContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL?

Tags: c#, office365, azure-active-directory

I took an example for AzureAD - Connection [from MSDN](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/aspnetmvc) which contains the following snippet:

```
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Settings.AzureADAuthority);

        // Generate the parameterized URL for Azure login.
        Uri authUri = authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL(
            Settings.O365UnifiedAPIResource, 
            Settings.ClientId,
            loginRedirectUri, 
            UserIdentifier.AnyUser, 
            null);
```

This example uses Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory - NuGet-package of version 2.19

The most current Version of that package (3.12) removed that method. Of course I could just use the old version but would prefer using the most current one.

So what should I use instead? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Method is an async now: GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync
Have a look here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/a1a560f3e8be91687a770d4ddd7a10b342f52e6d/src/ADAL.PCL/AuthenticationContext.cs Line 443

You may also look for some new Examples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples